# java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer , sql Dialect is not configured

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using spring boot 1.5, I want to get alerts grouped by their status (four status).thereby I'm using a native query in the repository. when I run that query it's giving me the result. but it doesnt work with the service.
the result I've got when I run with the console : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eson3nEHAIEr-jdEgkC1-tw2acRsW728

the service is :

```
  @Override
public List<DashboardAlertVO> countingStatus() {
    return alertRepository.countStatus()
            .stream()
            .map(o -> new DashboardAlertVO(AlertStatus.fromValue((String) o[0]),
                    ((Integer) o[1])))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

so I'm getting this error :

```
"message": "java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer",
```

I don't know what's matter really with this code. Please help ! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We can not type cast BigInteger to Integer by simply using integer keyword. Instead you should use the inbuilt method intValue() of BigInteger class to get the integer part.

```
@Override
public List<DashboardAlertVO> countingStatus() {
    return alertRepository.countStatus()
        .stream()
        .map(o -> new DashboardAlertVO(AlertStatus.fromValue((String) o[0]),
                (o[1].intValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```